# Calculate Matrix Determinants of minors!

Tags: python, math, matrix, scipy, scientific-computing

i want to caluculate Matrix determinants of minors in Python, maybe using scipy or some other package.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy/SciPy will do all this.

- Form sub-matrices by [removing rows and columns](http://www.scipy.org/PerformanceTips#head-2ce6af8fce6091d1084822099ce06f822bcc4213).
- Calculate determinants with [`linalg.det()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/linalg.html#finding-determinant).

Comment: Only 12 years later and the scipy link is already broken! I think it's here, and am not sure if the speed up is still valid https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/PerformanceTips ... will check at some point.

Comment: From a few quick checks on row deletion, it seems like np.delete is generally faster. Maybe a corner case for small matrices where handling it yourself might pay off 2x.

Answer (score 1):

To create the minor matrix you could use the function

```
def minor(M, i, j):
    M = np.delete(M, i, 0)
    M = np.delete(M, j, 1)
    return M
```

With this output

```
np.linalg.det(M)
```

Answer (score 0):

To create the principal minor determinants of a matrix and make the calculus for each one determinant, you would want to do this:

```
import numpy as np

# procedure for creating principal minor determinants
def minor(M, size):
    # size can be 2x2, 3x3, 4x4 etc.
    theMinor = []

    for i in range(size):
        clearList = []
        for j in range(size):
            clearList.append(M[i][j])

        theMinor.append(clearList)

    return theMinor


# procedure to handle the principal minor
def handleMinorPrincipals(A, n):
    # A is a square Matrix
    # n is number or rows and cols for A

    if n == 0:
        return None
    if n == 1:
        return A[0][0]

    # size 1x1 is calculated
    # we now look for other minors
    for i in range(1, n):
        # get the minor determinant
        minDet = minor(A, i + 1)

        # check if determinant is greater than 0
        if np.linalg.det(minDet) > 0:
            # do smth
        else:
            # smth else

    return
```

```
Example:

[[8. 8. 0. 0. 0.]
 [6. 6. 3. 0. 0.]
 [0. 4. 4. 4. 0.]
 [0. 0. 2. 2. 2.]
 [0. 0. 0. 2. 2.]]

size = 1 -> Minor is 

[8]

size = 2 -> Minor is

[[8. 8.]
[6. 6.]]

size = 3 -> Minor is

[[8. 8. 0.]
[6. 6. 3.]
[0. 4. 4]]
```